# ipython vs. python -m IPython

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

I recently installed ipython from a zip file and setup.py, but now I am unable to run it by just typing "ipython" in the terminal (on a Mac). It works fine if I type "python2.7 -m IPython". Any suggestions on how to make "ipython" work again?

I previously had it installed via pip, but it was linked to the wrong version of python.

Comment: If you downloaded the zip from github it is probably broken, github zip don't include submodules. Also if you have any error message, that would help.

Comment: I downloaded "ipython-2.1.0.zip" from https://github.com/ipython/ipython/releases.
If I type ipython in command, I simply get "-bash: ipython: command not found". It does work fine if I use "python2.7 -m IPython" though, including notebook mode.

Comment: Then ipython is not in your bash $PATH. Github zip are broken and last version is 2.3.0, not 2.1.0 Avoid github zips.

Comment: Fyi. I figured it out. I made a text file in /usr/bin called "ipython" with contents "python2.7 -m IPython" (effectively a bash script). Now if I type "ipython" in any folder, it starts ipython.

Comment: You probably want to use the following which is what IPython should install:```#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4
# This script was automatically generated by setup.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import start_ipython
    start_ipython()```

Comment: I'd suggest setting up a virtual environment with the 'right' version of python and pip installing ipython into the environment. Saves a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is here:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ipython
```

So what I did is

```
ln -s /Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ipython /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

Done. "ipython" works again.

I searched through "/" directory to find it.

(I'm using OS X 10.11.6)